# Error encountered with usage of != or <> operating for SOQL query in batch class

Tags: apex, soql, batch, dynamic-soql

I get the following error in Developer Console (logs) while executing this batch class with the following code snippet.

> 20:07:09:029 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found '('

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    final String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,MedConnect__Submission_Status__c FROM MedConnect__FDA_3500A_MedWatch_Report__c WHERE MedConnect__Submission_Status__c IN (\'Submitted\', \'Transmitted\', \'Ack1\', \'Ack2\') AND MedConnect__Report_Status__c NOT IN (\'Complete\')';
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

The above example use `!=`. Same error is received when using `<>` parameter.

However, the error goes away when I use `NOT IN` parameter. Can someone please explain what is going on here?

---

The code which errors out during anonymous execution is:

```
final String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,MedConnect__Submission_Status__c FROM MedConnect__FDA_3500A_MedWatch_Report__c WHERE MedConnect__Submission_Status__c IN (\'Submitted\', \'Transmitted\', \'Ack1\', \'Ack2\') AND MedConnect__Report_Status__c != (\'Complete\')';
return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use a *not equals* operator on a text field, you must use a single, quote wrapped value. Parentheses indicate a collection and will only work with `IN` or `NOT IN` operators.

A single value would look as follows:

```
String soql = 'SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Field__c != \'Single Value\''
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
{

    final String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,MedConnect__Submission_Status__c FROM MedConnect__FDA_3500A_MedWatch_Report__c WHERE MedConnect__Submission_Status__c IN (\'Submitted\', \'Transmitted\', \'Ack1\', \'Ack2\') AND MedConnect__Report_Status__c != \'Complete\'';
            return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}re
```